# Partial Date Match with Hibernate Search

Tags: hibernate, elasticsearch, hibernate-search

We have the following requirement

As part of a search a user may search on a person's date of birth. Generally speaking this works fine the user selects from a datepicker on the front end and the search works as expected.

However we now have a requirement where the user may not know the exact date of birth for example they might only know the year of birth.

What I have tried

```
@Basic
@Field
@Field(name = "dob_string", bridge = @FieldBridge(impl = CustomDateStringBridge.class) 
,analyzer = @Analyzer(definition = "dob_string_analyzer"))
@Column(name = "date_of_birth")
private Date dateOfBirth;
```

The CustomDateStringBridge class just returns the date as a string for example 19780418 which works as expected.

The problem is when we attempt to query on the dob_string field

We have the following as part of the overall query

```
             partialDOB = DIGIT_ONLY_PATTERN.matcher(partialDOB).replaceAll("");
             bool.must(queryBuilder.keyword()
            .wildcard()
            .onField("datesOfBirth.dob_string")
            .ignoreFieldBridge()
            .ignoreAnalyzer()
            .matching("*"+partialDOB+"*")
            .createQuery());
```

However this results in the following error

```
"type": "parse_exception",
    "reason": "failed to parse date field [*1979*] with format [ 
strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis]"
```

I have tried without the ignoreAnalyzer and ignoreFieldBridge but end up with different errors

Just wondering is it possible to do this type of wildcard search on a date? And if anyone has any idea about how to do so.

Thanks

Comment: I had a similar issue (I had user input is either year or month + year) but my approach was to parse the input in the application and then just use sql functions `month()` and `year()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'd recommend a different approach, because wildcard queries, especially with a leading wildcard, can perform very badly.

Instead, keep a date field, and take advantage of numeric queries.

- **Remove your bridge** so that the date stays a date
- Rely on [range queries](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#_range_queries) to find dates within a certain year, month, or day.

For example, to search for a given year:

```java
// Input
int yearAsInteger = ...;

// Replace this with the user timezone if your Date instances
// are created for a user timezone different from the system default
ZoneId timezone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
Year year = Year.of( yearAsInteger );
Date startOfYear = Date.from( year.atDay( 1 ).atStartOfDay( timezone ).toInstant() );
Date startOfNextYear = Date.from( year.plusYear( 1L ).atDay( 1 ).atStartOfDay( timezone ).toInstant() );

bool.must(queryBuilder.range()
            .onField("datesOfBirth.dateOfBirth")
            .from(startOfYear)
            .to(startOfNextYear).excludeLimit()
            .createQuery());
```

---

Now, if you really want to go with a string field... The problem is in your Elasticsearch mapping. Field `dob_string` is registered in Elasticsearch's mapping as a 'date' field, whereas you want it to be a string.

You should be able to tell Hibernate Search it's a string field by implementing [`MetadataProvidingFieldBridge`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#metadata-providing-field-bridge) in your bridge, and providing the field type this way:

```java
  @Override
  public void configureFieldMetadata(String name, FieldMetadataBuilder builder) {
      builder.field( name, FieldType.STRING );
  }
```

Don't forget to drop and re-create your Elasticsearch indexes after this change.

Alternatively, you can also move to [Hibernate Search 6](https://hibernate.org/search/releases/6.0/). It's in beta, but it's stable, nearing release, and Elasticsearch support is much better there (no longer experimental). However, the API is different, so if you already have an extended codebase, there will be significant work to migrate. I'm writing the migration guide as we speak.